# Angular2-Meteor: how to re-use components outside my app

Tags: meteor, angular

I have been following a tutorial to create a demo app using Angular2-Meteor.

Link to tutorial: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/

I have an external web page where I would like to use some components from the app.

This is the PartiesList component declaration, from the tutorial:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Parties} from '../../../collections/parties.ts';
import {PartiesForm} from '../parties-form/parties-form.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'parties-list',
  templateUrl: '/client/imports/parties-list/parties-list.html',
  directives: [PartiesForm]
})

export class PartiesList {
  parties: Mongo.Cursor;

  constructor() {
    this.parties = Parties.find();
  }

  removeParty(party) {
    Parties.remove(party._id);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use this component outside the app, in another html file, for example:

```
<body>
...
<parties-list></parties-list>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in an Angular application like

```
bootstrap(PartiesList)
```

or in the view of another Angular component.

Comment: I already did that, I can use the component inside my <app> tag, the component renders and it's functional. I wanted to know if it's possible to reuse it outside of the app html, in another web page.

Comment: This are the 2 ways how an Angular components can be used. Individually by `bootstrap()` and inside anOther Angular component.